# How can I get to top query of my result sumOfSalary

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(SUM(e.salary),0) as sumOfSalary, 
d.departName 
FROM
employee e 
JOIN depart d on (d.id = e.depart) 
GROUP BY d.departName
ORDER BY sumOfSalary desc
```

How can I return the highest value result from `sumOfSalary` without using LIMIT 1? im trying to use `MAX()` in `SUM(e.salary)` but it doesnt help I get an error #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: if you get an error, post the error message. Also it helps much if you get sample data and expected result

Comment: do you want to get highest salary per department or the highest salary across all departments or the department with the highest summarized salary?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler yes across all department

Comment: What's wrong with LIMIT 1???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just the max salary among all departments (I hope that I got your question correctly!), then use a nested query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MAX(sumOfSalary),0) FROM (
SELECT 
SUM(e.salary) as sumOfSalary, d.departName 
FROM employee e 
JOIN depart d on d.id = e.depart)
GROUP BY d.departName
) AS ss
```

Comment: I need to get the highest salaries across all department

Comment: So, you need only one salary, the highest one among all departments? Am I correct?

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: There's been a mistype. The last row is `) AS ss`.

Comment: Thank this works great! been scratching my head how to do that

Comment: @ProgrammerDummy glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Use LIMIT to return only the top result of the query:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(SUM(e.salary),0) as sumOfSalary, 
    d.departName 
FROM
    employee e 
JOIN depart d 
    on (d.id = e.depart) 
GROUP BY d.departName
ORDER BY sumOfSalary desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: sorry forgot to include that I am not suppose to use limit

Comment: why not use limit ?

Comment: Its an activity for school condition is not to use any limit to get the correct result

Answer (score 0):

as you use format, your result are not sorted by numeric value but alphabetical order 
so '600'  comes before '3000' in descending order

```
    select departName, format(max(sumOfSalary),0) from 
 (SELECT 
    SUM(e.salary) as sumOfSalary, 
    d.departName 
    FROM
    employee e 
    JOIN depart d on (d.id = e.depart) 
    GROUP BY d.departName
    ORDER BY SUM(e.salary) desc limit 1) as nested
```